# OSGI cannot link to native method via JNI at runtime

Tags: dll, java-native-interface, osgi, swig

I am trying to use a method from a DLL in a OSGI-bundle. The DLL gets loaded correctly in OSGI, but I still get an java unsatisfied link error, the native method is not found!

When deployed standalone in Java only (no OSGI), the DLL gets loaded and run perfectly.

Here's what I did:

- I generated a JNI bridge to my C++ compiled DLL through SWIG.
- I specified the package name when calling swig.
- I declared the dll inclusion in my Maven pom.xml xml element, which generates a correct Manifest file.
- Loading of the DLL libraries is done without any errors / warnings

What truly puzzles me is that the symbols in the dll seem to not be found:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.bmw.corona.components.sample.impl.generated.AdasDeconstructorJNI.swig_module_init()V

The problem is when coupling it with OSGI, I'm guessing somewhere in OSGI's ClassLoader.

The method in the dll seems to have a the correct signature :

> _Java_com_bmw_corona_components_sample_impl_generated_AdasDeconstructorJNI_swig_1module_1init@8

with the following prototype in the generated SWIG file:

> SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_AdasDeconstructorJNI_swig_1module_1init(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls)

I was triple-sure to check that the Manifest includes the Bundle Native instruction.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're triple sure that you have a bundle native header... but not willing to show us what it looks like? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was twofold. First, the methods weren't found do to Visual Studio 2010's method name mangling. I added a linker directive :

`#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:__Java_com_bmw_corona_components_sample_impl_AdasDeconstructorJNI_swig_module_init=_Java_com_bmw_corona_components_sample_impl_AdasDeconstructorJNI_swig_1module_1init@8")`

It does take a bit of time for all the bundles (more than 100) to get up and running, and I do get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` the first couple of seconds after launch. Afterwards, everything seems to be working fine. And the nullPointerException is gone..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consult this wiki article: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Dependencies_In_Native_Code

It is hard to tell from your description, but it sound like you have 2 native libs. One with the JNI entry points and the other with the real native function. The above wiki article discusses the dependencies from the JNI native lib to other native libs.

Comment: I only have one entry point to the DLL and it is the JNI entry point. From there, the DLL symbols get loaded into the virtual machine with their Java-signatures.

The wiki is really helpful in understanding the library load mechanism. However, I am working on Windows which means the library loader cache will be consulted and the dll found there.

The dll _is_ loaded, but somehow no access is given to the internal symbols.

Comment: (.. I mean the signatures for the method calls from the abstract classes in the dll to the implmenentations in the Java classes get loaded into the VM). But let's not complicate things, the original entry point is the JNI entry function swig_module_init().